# Large Haskell array prevents the compilation with GHC

Tags: arrays, haskell, ghc

I'm making an array of complex numbers in Haskell (**array** package) with the function `array`. The list of associations is big: `512 x 512` (of course I didn't fill it by hands). The file size is approximately 11Mb.

When I run `stack build`, here is the error message generated when compiling this module:

```
ghc-9.2.8.exe: osCommitMemory: VirtualAlloc MEM_COMMIT failed to commit 1048576 bytes of memory  (error code: 1455): The paging file is too small for this operation to complete.

Error: [S-7282]
       Stack failed to execute the build plan.

       While executing the build plan, Stack encountered the error:

       [S-7011]
       While building package HaskellImages-0.1.0.0 (scroll up to its section to see the error)
       using:
       C:\Users\hl45369\AppData\Roaming\stack\setup-exe-cache\x86_64-windows\Cabal-simple_9p6GVs8J_3.6.3.0_ghc-9.2.8.exe --verbose=1 --builddir=.stack-work\dist\8a54c84f build lib:HaskellImages --ghc-options " -fdiagnostics-color=always"
       Process exited with code: ExitFailure 251
```

Is there something I can do? What is the "paging file"? Is it due to a lack of RAM?

The array I construct is an unboxed array. Is there another type of array which requires less memory?

I tried nothing because I have no clue about this problem.

Comment: Perhaps try reading the array from a file.

Comment: So you wrote the array out as a big list literal in a giant `.hs` source file? That's clearly not a good approach, and wouldn't be good even if GHC was able to handle this. Best is to load the array from a suitable file (perhaps `.png`) at runtime. Alternatively it _should_ be possible to hard-bake it into the executable, but you should use Template Haskell for doing this.

Comment: I believe I have seen this issue a few years ago: GHC doesn't cope with large list/string/array literals in the code. I thought it was solved, though. If everything else fails, you could keep your data in a separate file and use `unsafePerformIO` to bind it to a global array constant. If you can load it without `unsafe` stuff, I'd do so instead, but this is one of the few rare cases where it's OK to use unsafe functions. Just be sure the external file isn't modified at runtime.

Comment: @n.m.couldbeanAI That's what I finally did. With a CSV file (package **cassava**). Very fast!